# How to mass prepend text from filename into multiple existing files

Tags: windows, command-line

I have files with the following name

- GB_20141001
- JPN_20141001
- GB_20141002
- TH_20141003

I want the date at the end of file name to prepended to its content. The content of each file may look like this

```
ABD10224
CHG20991
GHJ02933
```

and would become this:

```
20141001
ABD10224
CHG20991
GHJ02933
```

is it possible to create a batch file to do that

Comment: This is more of a SO question and for that to be a great question you need to at least so some effort have you tried anything already?

Comment: I tried for single file but couldn't get the date part.

Answer (score 1):

*Note - None of this code is tested, so there may be some bugs. But the concepts are all correct*

If none of your files have more than one `_`, then:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=_ delims=_ tokens=1,2" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *_????????^|findstr /rx "[^._][^._]*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"'
) do ((
  echo %%B
  type "%%A_%%B"
) >"%%A_%%B.new" & move /y "%%A_%%B.new" "%%A_%%B" >nul )
```

If there may be more than one `_`, then:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "eol=_ delims=_ tokens=1,2" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d *_????????^|findstr /rx "[^.][^.]*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"'
) do call :processFile "%%F"
exit /b

:processFile
set "file=%~1"
for %%A in ("%file:_=" "%") do set "dt=%%A"
>"%~1.new" (
  echo %dt%
  type %1
)
move /y "%~1.new" %1 >nul
exit /b
```

Or, if you get a copy of [repl.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053), it simplifies to:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=: tokens=1,2" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *_????????^|repl "^[^.]+_(\d{8})$" "$&:$1" a'
) do ((
  echo %%B
  type "%%A"
) >"%%A.new" & move /y "%%A.new" "%%A" >nul )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cygwin installed or otherwise have access to a `bash` shell, then try this:

```
for f in *; do sed -i "1 s/^/${f##*_}\n/" "$f"; done
```

#### How it works

- `for f in *; do`

  This starts a loop over all files in the current directory.
- `sed -i "1 s/^/${f##*_}\n/" "$f"`

  `sed` is the tool for editing files.  `-i` tells `sed` to edit the file in-place.  `1` tells the `sed` to apply this change only to the first line.  `s/^/${f##*_}\n/` is a substitute command.  It normally looks something like `s/old/new/`.  In our case, old is `^` which is a regular expression that matches at the beginning of a line.  The beginning of the line is replaced with `${f##*_}\n/` where `${f##*_}` is the file name with everything up through the last underline character removed and `\n` is  new line character.   This places the date on a new line at the beginning of the file
- `done`

  This marks the end of the `for` loop.

#### Example

Let us start with a directory with the sample file:

```
$ ls
GB_20141001
$ cat GB_20141001 
ABD10224
CHG20991
GHJ02933
```

We apply our command:

```
$ for f in *; do sed -i "1 s/^/${f##*_}\n/" "$f"; done
```

The file now has the date as the first line:

```
$ cat GB_20141001 
20141001
ABD10224
CHG20991
GHJ02933
```

Comment: Note the Windows tag.  This would require some unix tool ports such as cygwin.

Comment: @Paul Oops.  Thanks.  Answer now updated with that qualifier.

Comment: is there anything with pure windows

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul Most likely, but I am not the right person to provide that answer.